# IPv6 CIDR в Regex

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Здрaвствуйте. Каким образом можно сделать Regex, который покроет следующий диапазон IPv6: `2001:4860::/34`?

Comment: если я не ошибаюсь, диапазон 2001:4860:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000 - 2001:4860:3fff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff . Первые 8 цифр постоянные, следущая 0-3, потом любые

Comment: @splash58 а нет каких-нибудь автоматических конвертеров, которые соберут регулярное выражение под указанный диапазон?

Comment: не знаю - мне никогда не было надо. почти наверняка что-то  есть